# SQL server semi-database mirroring

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

We have the following problem:Our customer has a the life database.Sometimes,we face bugs that are due to data in life,those bugs doesn't appear in our staging and development databases because they are usually related to the actual data.
So, for accurate debugging,we need to have the same copy of life data in another database.This database should be synchronized with the life database (either automatically or in-demand),so that we can replicate the erroneous scenarios without impacting the actual data.How can we perform that?Is it better to create this "semi-mirror" in the staging itself? As a final note,I don't want the changes from the "semi-mirror" database to be reflected one the life, Only from the life to the "semi-mirror".

Answer (score 1):

Per definition you ahve no staging database. Staging should reflect real world, so contain real world data (and size) and run on a similar system.

Your customer should take a backup and you load it into staging. You do that regularly (weekly, monthly, after updates) to make sure you are in sync. Standad procecedure in every project I have ever been that worked well.

Comment: Is there any automated way to do that?or should it be done manually using backup & restore mechanism.

Comment: Depends. Any aministrator worth a cent can script this, so it can be automated.